# C++ internal CMake error with checking pthread

Tags: c++, cmake

I have CMakeLists.txt with the following instructions:

```
set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

...
target_link_libraries(zipkin Threads::Threads ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${WIN32_LIBRARIES})
```

But when I try to build it, I have the following errors in the CMakeError.log:

```
13 CMakeFiles/cmTC_78fe1.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
14 CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
15 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
16 CMakeFiles/cmTC_78fe1.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_78fe1' failed
17 make[2]: *** [cmTC_78fe1] Error 1
18 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/vbalun/Desktop/dsp/dsp-deps/zipkin-cpp-opentracing/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
19 Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_78fe1/fast' failed
20 make[1]: *** [cmTC_78fe1/fast] Error 2
21 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vbalun/Desktop/dsp/dsp-deps/zipkin-cpp-opentracing/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
22 
23 File /home/vbalun/Desktop/dsp/dsp-deps/zipkin-cpp-opentracing/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
24 /* */
25 #include <pthread.h>
26 
27 int main(int argc, char** argv)
28 {
29   (void)argv;
30 #ifndef pthread_create
31   return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
32 #else
33   (void)argc;
34   return 0;
35 #endif
36 }
```

CMake creates new temp file for checking pthread and I think It's internal CMake error, but how can I fix it?
CMake(3.10.2) and Ubuntu(18.04)

Comment: Are you trying to use `pthread` on Windows?

Comment: "CMake creates new temp file for checking pthread and I think It's internal CMake error" - No, you think wrong, there is no "internal CMake errors" in the `CMakeError.log` file. If you got an error message in `cmake` output, then show that message (add it to the question post). Otherwise, there is no reason to look into `CMakeError.log`.

Comment: Please update your question post with the CMake console output.